# Oracle SQL join query to find highest salary

Tags: oracle, join, top-n

So I have two tables salary and emp whose definition is shown as below

[[image]

I am tring to create a query that Find the employee who draws the maximum salary and Display the  employee details along with the nationality.

I created this query

```
select empcode,
       max(basic) as "Highest Sal"
 from salary 
    join emp on empcode;
```

Please help with this

Answer (score 2):

Your query uses a simple aggregate `max(basic)` which would find the highest salary. Except you need to join to the EMP table to display other details. This means you can't use aggregation, because we need to GROUP BY the non-aggregated columns, which would make a nonsense of the query.

Fortunately we can solve the problem with an analytic function. The subquery selects all the relevant information and ranks each employee by salary, with a rank of 1 being the highest paid. We use `rank()` here because that will handle ties: two employees with the same `basic` will be in the same rank.

```
select empcode
           , empname
           , nationality
           , "Highest Sal" 
from (
    select emp.empcode
           , emp.empname
           , emp.nationality
           ,  salary.basic as "Highest Sal" 
           , rank() over (order by salary.basic desc ) as rnk
    from salary join emp on emp.empcode = salary.empcode
)
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Looks good though I have tried it and it gives an error at line 12: ORA-00920: INVALID RELATIONAL OPERATOR

Answer (score 1):

> Find the employee who draws the maximum salary

An employee can have multiple salaries in your datamodel. An employee's (total) salary hence is the sum of these. You want to find the maximum salary per employee and show the employee(s) earning that much.

You can use `MAX OVER` to find the maximum sum:

```
select e.*, s.total_salary
from emp e
join 
(
  select
    empcode, 
    sum(basic) as total_salary,
    max(sum(basic)) over () as max_total_salary
  from salary
) s on s.empcode = e.empcode and s.total_salary = s.max_total_salary
order by e.empcode;
```

Comment: Keen piece of observation. I suspect the 1:M relationship is a flaw in the data model rather than an actual business rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT E.EmpCode, E.EmpName, E.DOB, E.DOJ, E.DeptCode, E.DesgCode, E.PhNo, 
E.Qualification, E.Nationality, S.Basic, S.HRA, S.TA, S.UTA, S.OTRate 
FROM EMP AS E JOIN SALARY AS S ON (E.EmpCode = S.EmpCode) order by S.Basic desc) 
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: `==` is not valid Oracle syntax. Also this query will not produce a correct solution if there are two employees both earning the highest `basic` salary.